# Hotmail 'Something went wrong' message when trying to open inbox after adding new email alias to VSTS account

Tags: email, alias, hotmail

I recently added a new email alias (my work email address) to my Microsoft ID following instructions here:

https://nkdagility.com/using-multiple-email-alias-existing-microsoft-id/

I added the new address as my primary email alias here: https://account.live.com/names/Manage

I can no longer access my inbox with an error as follows:

:-(
Something went wrong
Something went wrong and we couldn't complete your request.
X-OWA-Error: Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.DatabaseNotFoundException
X-OWA-Version: 15.1.609.7

I've even now tried to set my old (hotmail) address as the primary email alias, but I still can't access my inbox. Is there someone who knows how I can resolve this problem, or know how I can get support from Microsoft to resolve this problem? I've been unable to access my hotmail account for several days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, just now I found the solution:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-on-Outlook-com-8c95d913-d96b-4065-9171-e1fa44b03ff5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

"When you try to login to your mailbox that connects to an Exchange Server, you might receive a "Something went wrong" page, with error DatabaseNotFoundException.

To resolve this issue, login to your account using this link: http://outlook.live.com/OWA.
If you still get the error, add an Outlook.com alias to your account, (if you don’t already have one) and use that alias as your primary alias.

To learn more about Outlook.com aliases, see Add or remove an email alias in Outlook.com."

This worked!